# Javascript allowing musescore text to be rendered in a browser

Tags: javascript, qt, rendering, music-notation

I need a good javascript library that can render musical notation to a browser page. [`VexFlow`](http://www.vexflow.com/docs/tutorial.html) seemed promising, but it doesn't look like it could support multiple staves like are done in the piano or larger group orchestrations, and frankly a lot of things about it seem shaky.

What I'd really love is to have an interface to render [Musescore](http://musescore.org/en), but my looking around their site doesn't seem very encouraging, because of their use of the qt framework. Any advice? Methods for porting the musescore codebase into a js file? Or even recommendations of other libraries? I'm hoping to not have to extend `VexFlow` myself, but I will if I have to.

Comment: If you want to use Vexflow to render a grand staff/multiple staves, there's example code here: https://github.com/0xfe/vexflow/issues/134. I'm pretty sure that you could extend that to n staves.

Comment: There's a [companion website](http://musescore.com/) where users can upload and share MuseScore files. In a sheet page there's a player that renders and plays the score, I don't know how it's done, but you may want to check that and / or contact them on the mailing list.